# JQPlot date axis is not plotting graph

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqplot

I am using JQPlot trying to draw a graph which contains dates. But I cant able to draw the graph, but i tried the sample application it is working fine. But whenever i pass my array it is not working, can anyone please help what i am doing wrong? Below is the code i am using.

```
$.get("${contextPath}/qos/graphJQPlot", $("#qosForm").serialize()).done(function(content) {
        $.each(content, function (index1, value1) {
            var innerArray = [];
            $.each(value1, function (index2, value2) {
                innerArray.push(value2, index2);
                console.log(index2);
                console.log(value2);
            })
            outerArray.push(innerArray);
        })

        var line1=[['2008-09-30 4:00PM',4], ['2008-10-30 4:00PM',6.5], ['2008-11-30 4:00PM',5.7], ['2008-12-30 4:00PM',9], ['2009-01-30 4:00PM',8.2]];
        var plot3 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [outerArray],
                  {
                    title:'Line Style Options',
                    axes:{
                        xaxis:{
                          renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer, 
                          tickOptions:{formatString:'%b %#d, %y'}/* ,
                          min:'2013-09-14',
                          max:'2013-09-21',
                          tickInterval:'1 day' */
                          /* ,
                          tickOptions:{formatString:'%b %#d, %Y'},

                           */
                        }
                      }
                  }
                );
    });
```

If i pause an line1 to jqPlot it is working fine, but if i pass an outerArray it is not working.

Comment: Can you log outerArray structure to find if it's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to include jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.js plugins

Comment: Please provide context and proper formatting for your proposed answer so it might be helpful to others.